# Google Endpoints frontend

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new into this whole Endpoints thing and was wondering if the Endpoints have the possibility to easily create (or has default) simple CRUD frontend for the models I create just like it's the case with Win API or something like that...?

Or does it have to be developed separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that Endpoints currently generate any simple CRUD frontend for the models.

What Endpoints can help you with is to generate the client libraries (Java, Python, iOS) that can help you integrate easily with your client code. Additionally, there is also a Java Script client library that you can use to invoke your Endpoints API. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/